# Uncaught ReferenceError: rgba is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am attempting to make a simple animation that would change a color of a font, but I am struggling with said reference error. Can anyone point me to the right direction, please? I have already installed color animation jQuery-plugin.

HTML:

```
<ul class="menu"> 
<li><a href="">ABOUT US</a></li>        
<li><a href="">CONTACT</a></li>   
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$('.menu').find('a').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).css({color: rgba(239, 231, 35, 0.8)});
});
```

Comment: `'rgba(239, 231, 35, 0.8)'`  you need to surround text with quotes.  Moreso when that text can be interpreted as a function call.

Comment: `$(this).css({color: 'rgba(239, 231, 35, 0.8)'});`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your JavaScript code is missing some quotes.

Change this line:

```
$(this).css({color: rgba(239, 231, 35, 0.8)});
```

To this:

```
$(this).css({'color':'rgba(239, 231, 35, 0.8)'});
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using jQuery color animation, then the below code would do the trick:

```
$(this).animate({color: 'rgba(239, 231, 35, 0.8)'});
```